# Getting the value of dropdownlist in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following the html/php code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Voiture</title>
</head>

<body>
    Welcome<br>
    <form method="post" action="">
        Liste de voiture<select name="selected" id="selected">
            <?php
            $sql = 'select Type from voiture';
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            $json = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if(!in_array($row['Type'], $json)){
                    $json[] = $row['Type'];
                    echo '<option name = "'.$row['Type'].'">'.$row['Type'].'</option>';
                }
            }
               ?>

        </select> <br>

        <span id="sel" name="sel"></span>
        <table border="1">
            <tr id="header">
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td>Couleur</td>
                <td>Prix</td>
                <td>User</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" hidden>
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#selected').on('change',function(){
                $('#sel').text(document.getElementById('selected').value);
                $.getJSON('phpVoiture.php',function(data){
                    for (var x = 0 ; x < data.length ; x++){
                        $('<tr><td>'+data[x]['type']+'</td>'+'<td>'+data[x]['Model']+
                                '</td><td>'+data[x]['Couleur']+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[x]['Prix']+'</td>'+'<td></td></tr>').insertAfter($('#header'));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following php page :

```
<?php

require_once ('./dbConnect.php');
include ('./Voiture.php');

$sel = $_POST['selected'];
$conn = mysqli_connect(servername, username, password, db ,port);
$query = "select * from voiture where Type = '".sel."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$json = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $json[] = [
            'type' => $row['Type'],
            'model' => $row['Model'],
            'couleur' => $row['Couleur'],
            'prix' => $row['Prix']
        ];
    }
}
else{
    echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

The problem is that when I select an option in the drop down list nothing happens. I want the query in the second php page to select the cars that have the type that I selected in the drop down list. I tried troubleshooting by echo an alert in both pages that have the value of the selected option, but this step also failed, so I think there is an issue with retrieving the value of the selected option. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be careful... [Look at this first](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), and then add a `$ ` so your line looks like : `$query = "select * from voiture where Type = '".$sel."'";`

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending the selected value to the server.  Add it to the AJAX call:

```
$.getJSON('phpVoiture.php', { selected: $('#selected').val() }, function(data){
    //...
});
```

Also, your `<option>` elements don't *have* values.  You used `name` instead, but that belongs on the `<select>`.  Use `value`:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['Type'].'">'.$row['Type'].'</option>';
```

Additionally, you're using a GET request instead of a POST request.  So you need to look for the value in the `$_GET` array:

```
$sel = $_GET['selected'];
```

You have other typos too, such as an incorrect use of a variable in PHP:

```
"...".sel."..."
```

would be:

```
"...".$sel."..."
```

Though this brings up a point about [**SQL injection**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  You really shouldn't be directly concatenating the variable like that at all.  Instead, [use prepared statements with query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

It's *entirely possible* that there continue to be other mistakes in the code I simply haven't spotted yet.  You'll want your debugging to include two things:

1. Looking at your PHP logs for errors.
2. Using your browser's debugging tools to observe the AJAX request/response.

Comment: His options use `name` instead of `value`, which is also incorrect